# Oracle SQL, insert a query inside a row like string/text

Tags: sql, oracle, text

Im trying to insert a Query inside my db as string (when user clicks the app execute this query and show charts).

```
Select DECODE (VERSION_JPA,
               1, 'Abierto',
               2, 'Cerrado',
                  'Desconocido') as "LABEL",
       'Simulacion' AS "SERIE",
       count(VERSION_JPA) as "VALUE" 
FROM EVENTOS 
WHERE TIPO = 'simulacion'
group by VERSION_JPA
```

This Query works in Aqua Data. To insert inside the DB y use the double ' and i delete the " because i read that the " doesnt work in oracle. Finally i insert this in my DB:

```
   ' Select DECODE (VERSION_JPA,
                   1, ''Abierto'',
                   2, ''Cerrado'',
                      ''Desconocido'') as ''LABEL'',
           ''Simulacion'' AS ''SERIE'',
           count(VERSION_JPA) as ''VALUE'' 
    FROM EVENTOS 
    WHERE TIPO = ''simulacion''
    group by VERSION_JPA '
```

But still not working. What am i doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: This wouldn't be good idea to store SQL query inside db and executing later. it will make your application vulnerable

Comment: The insert doesn't work, or trying to execute this query (how?) doesn't work? What error do you get? The aliases still need double-quotes ('"LABEL"') or no quotes at all, but not sure if you're getting to a point where that matters... the `group by` also won't be valid.

Comment: FYI, you can escape all `'` by `''` from your SQL query which you want to store in db.

Comment: Log1c im not the creator of the app, i hate the querys inside DB xD.
@AlexPoole the inser works correctly, Execute the query inside the row is my problem.

Finally Patrick and Alex got me the reason, Aliases need the double quote or delete the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get rid of the `''` around `LABEL` etc.

Use this:

```
' Select DECODE (VERSION_JPA,
               1, ''Abierto'',
               2, ''Cerrado'',
                  ''Desconocido'') as LABEL,
       ''Simulacion'' AS SERIE,
       count(VERSION_JPA) as VALUE 
FROM EVENTOS 
WHERE TIPO = ''simulacion''
group by VERSION_JPA '
```

Comment: Thank you, now i see my problem. Aliases don't needed the double quote.
Now it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ORACLE 10 or above, you may use your own quotation marks. The format is
q'{your quotation mark}string{your quotation mark}'

So, using " will be simpler (you don't need to modify your string):

```
select q'"Select DECODE (VERSION_JPA,
          1, 'Abierto',
          2, 'Cerrado',
          'Desconocido') as LABEL,
   'Simulacion' AS SERIE,
   count(VERSION_JPA) as VALUE
FROM EVENTOS 
WHERE TIPO = 'simulacion'
group by VERSION_JPA"' select_statement
from dual
```